# how to evaluate svd similar items?

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, svd

for a task like recommending a item for a user, I can split dataset in two: traning and test datasets, and I can evaluate the result by using mean absolute error. However, when I need to find similar items of a item, I don't know how to evaluate the results.for example,

input:

```
    userid,itemid,score
    1,      123,    5
    2,      222,    1
    ....
```

```
svd.similar(123)
```

the output maybe: (222,0.98),(121,0.78)...
I don't know the similar items found from svd are good or not, how to evaluate the result?

Comment: You might want to define a similarity function (distance function) first. Then similarity can be determined and compared.

Comment: yeah, you are right, could you answer this question and I'll accept it

Comment: Why you do not compute for example, MSE1 for (222,0.98) and MSE2 for (121,0.78) and then, you decide based on the better MSE value, which item to choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to define a similarity function (distance function) first, e.g., cosine distance/euclidean distance. Then similarity can be determined and compared.